# How to evaluate the parameter of a function called from within decorator's wrapper?

Tags: python, python-decorators

Inside the decorator's `require_registered`  wrapper, how do I check if "John" is in registered users?

```
def require_registered(some_function):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        if username_parameter_from_login_function in registered_users: #how to replace "username_parameter_from_login_function"?
            some_function(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print("User is not registed")

    return wrapper

@require_registered
def login(username):
    print(username + ' has been logged in')

login('John')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your `wrapper` function to take `username` as a parameter as well:

```
def wrapper(username, *args, **kwargs):
    if username in registered_users:
        some_function(username, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        print("User is not registed")
```

Comment: Thanks blhsing, but is there any way to leave the function open to take any number of parameters? I was thinking that dissecting the `login` function to get to its `username` parameter value is somehow possible.

Comment: Sure, you can still have variable arguments and variable keyword arguments in your wrapper. I've updated my answer then.